# how to find leaves of a tree

Tags: algorithm, graph

There is a problem that wants to find the center of a tree and I want to delete the leaves until there are more than 2 vertices.
But how can I find the leaves ?

PS sorry for my English

Comment: Do you mean the "leaves of a tree"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: I have just seen you probably have a rooted tree. You can make a DFS of the tree and when from the current node you don't have an edge to a node different from the parent, then you have found a leaf.

Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_%28graph_theory%29):

> The degree of a vertex in a graph is
>   the number of edges incident to it. An
>   isolated vertex is a vertex with
>   degree zero; that is, a vertex that is
>   not an endpoint of any edge. A leaf
>   vertex (also pendant vertex) is a
>   vertex with degree one.

Just count the degree of every node. If it is `1` then you have a leaf.